# Are there flights from the Salar de Uyuni to Arequipa (Peru)?

Tags: air-travel, airports, peru, bolivia, salar-de-uyuni

Are there flights from the Salar de Uyuni to Arequipa (Peru) ? Or any recommended airport nearby Arequipa, you can suggest me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nearest airport, UYU, is a domestic airport; you will need to connect at La Paz (LPB). [Amaszonas](http://www.amaszonas.com/) and [TAM](http://www.tam.bo/) offer UYU-LPB services.

Arequipa, for its part, has limited international service, and you would need to connect on a LAN or TACA flight through Lima (LIM).

Comment: Thanks. I checked Amaszonas, and I noticed the price for the flight La Paz-Uyuni is always the same regardless how much in advance you reserve it: 145 euros. For example, there is a flight tomorrow for 145 euros as well. Does this mean I can buy the ticket the day before, once I'm there ?

Comment: @Patrick I can't say for certain; I haven't been in that part of the world in 6 years. If it's the same price, however, why not just make the reservation now and have peace of mind?

Comment: Because I would like to keep my travel as much flexible as I can. If I can reserve the flight 1 or 2 days before it would be great

Comment: It really depends. Just two months ago, I was there and flights were booked going for a few days ahead but I managed to book a next day return flight from Uyuni.